# Laravel trying to get property of a non-object (when pushed to server)

Tags: laravel

Locally this code works:

```
$DDLPartner->contentEnabled = 1;
```

But when I deploy on server I got this error:

**Trying to get property of non-object**

Sure, whan I change to **["contentEnabled"]**, it works but other things get broken.

This becomes very annoying, can someone help.

Comment: I cannot think of any situations where different environments would alter data from an object to an array. Is $DDLPartner pulled from a query? Is this line in the controller or view?

Comment: I coulnd't think also - this was a very strange logical bug which made me crazy. Problem was that on server, database table was truncated (empty), but locally it has some data inside. So even after git push, code was identical on both sides - but tables content were not.